# On page refresh Projects Context is returning projectsMap as undefined. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I refresh the Projects page, my Projects Context is returning `projectsMap` as undefined causing the error: `Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`. However, when I comment out

```
**{
    Object.keys(projectsMap).map((id) => {
        const projects = projectsMap[id];
        return (
            <h1 key={id}>{projects.name}</h1>
        );
    })
}**
```

and uncomment the code I don't have any errors. I assume this has to do with the async await assignment of projectMap to the return value from `getProjects(currentUser)`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code from firebase.utils for getProjects, the projects.context file and the **projects.component.jsx** files respctivly.

**firebase.utils.js**:

```
export const getProjects = async (userAuth) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;
    const projectsCollectionRef = collection(
        db,
        "users",
        userAuth.uid,
        "projects"
    );
    const q = query(projectsCollectionRef);
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        const projectMap = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((acc, docSnapshot) => {
            const id = docSnapshot.id;
            const { name } = docSnapshot.data();
            acc[id] = {id, name};
            return acc;
        }, {});
        return projectMap;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error getting project docs.");
      }
};
```

**projects.context.jsx**:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./user.context";
    
import { getProjects } from "../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";
    
export const ProjectsContext = createContext({
    projectsMap: {},
});
    
export const ProjectProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [projectsMap, setProjectsMap] = useState({});
    const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getProjectsMap = async () => {
            const projectMap = await getProjects(currentUser);
            setProjectsMap(projectMap);
        };
        getProjectsMap();
    });
    
    const value = { projectsMap };
    
    return (
        <ProjectsContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ProjectsContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

**Projects.jsx**:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
        
import { UserContext } from "../../contexts/user.context";
import { ProjectsContext } from "../../contexts/projects.context";
        
import { getProjects } from "../../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";
import CreateProjectForm from "../../components/create-project/Create-Project-Form.component";
        
const Projects = () => {
    const { projectsMap } = useContext(ProjectsContext);
    
    return (
        <>
            <CreateProjectForm />
            {
                Object.keys(projectsMap).map((id) => {
                    const projects = projectsMap[id];
                    return (
                        <h1 key={id}>{projects.name}</h1>
                    );
                })
            }
            <Outlet />
        </>
    );
};  

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change `setProjectsMap(projectMap)` to

```
projectMap ? setProjectsMap(projectMap) : setProjectsMap({});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).